# Unmet build dependencies: dh-virtualenv (>= 0.8)

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, deb, dpkg

I am trying to combine Debian packaging with self-contained virtualenv based Python deployments following [this](http://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/tutorial.html) tutorial using dh-virtualenv.

**debian/compat**:

```
9
```

**debian/control**:

```
Source: project
Section: python
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Andrei <foo@bar.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python, dh-virtualenv (>= 0.8)
Standards-Version: 3.9.5

Package: project
Architecture: any
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1), python2.7 | python2.6, ${misc:Pre-Depends}
Depends: ${python:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: test project
```

**debian/rules**:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
  dh $@ --with python-virtualenv
```

**debian/changelog**:

```
project (0.1.0) unstable; urgency=low

  * Initial release.

 -- Andrei <foo@bar.com>  Sun, 15 Jan 2017 23:46:39 +0300
```

After the execution of following command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

**I got following message**:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: source package project
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.1.0
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Andrei <foo@bar.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build project
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: dh-virtualenv (>= 0.8)
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install `dh-virtualenv` package from `backports`to solve the unmet dependencies , the current version on debian jessie  is `0.7` `< 0.8` , the backported version is `0.10` `> 0.8`.

Edit your `sources.list` by adding the following line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

then install `dh-virtualenv` as follows:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install dh-virtualenv
```

Comment: Sorry, I know it's an old question/answer but could you just say where is that sources.list file? Thanks!

Comment: found it, it's in /etc/apt